# struts application not working in linux tomcat server

Tags: java, apache, struts, tomcat7, struts1

I have a simple struts program working perfectly in windows environment with tomcat 7 as server. But I deployed the application in linux environment with tomcat 7 as server, the application is not running. It shows 404 error. Please help me to resolve the problem.

I am getting error as like this:
type Exception report

Message:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot
>   find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection

Description:

> The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from
>   fulfilling this request.

Exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:112)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.lookup(FormTag.java:747)
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:443)
    org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fform_005f0(login_jsp.java:147)
    org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.32 logs.
```

Comment: Will also need to see the configuration of the action in question. Right now it looks like you're hitting a JSP page directly but using S1 tags on the page, which IIRC won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did your included the jar correctly while creating the war file. Please check following jar are available in the WEB-INF/Lib folder of your project

1. antlr-2.7.6.jar
2. commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
3. commons-chain-1.2.jar
4. commons-collections-3.1.jar
5. commons-digester-2.0.jar
6. commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
7. commons-io-2.0.1.jar
8. commons-lang-2.5.jar
9. commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
10. commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
11. commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
12. dom4j-1.6.1.jar
13. hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
14. hibernate3.jar
15. javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
16. jstl-api-1.2.jar
17. jstl-impl-1.2.jar
18. jta-1.1.jar
19. mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar
20. ognl-3.0.1.jar
21. slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
22. slf4j-log4j12-1.6.2.jar
23. spring-beans-2.5.6.jar
24. spring-context-2.5.6.jar
25. spring-core-2.5.6.jar
26. spring-test-2.5.6.jar
27. spring-web-2.5.6.jar
28. struts2-core-2.2.3.1.jar
29. xwork-core-2.2.3.1.jar